# Wildfly starting out of nowhere

Tags: postgresql, maven, netbeans, jboss, wildfly

I am trying to use JPA on a Netbeans maven web project with postgre DB. 
I did all the configurations (on standalone.xml, module.xml) to run the wildfly and it's working fine (I can run the localhost:8080 and use the wildfly service)

But when I try to run the project, it says that the port 8080is already in use.

> ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001:
>   Failed to start service jboss.undertow.listener.default:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   jboss.undertow.listener.default: Address already in use
>   /127.0.0.1:8080

After some research, I decided do run "killall -9 java" to stop the wildfly. Ok, after doing that I could, as expected, not access localhost:8080 anymore. So I opened Netbeans, ran the project again and..... 8080 already in use.

I went to the command line again to check it and, yes, wildfly was started, and it can't be started on Netbeans. And if I go to localhost:8080 there it is, wildfly running from "somewhere".

Whst can be starting the wildfly service?

Comment: Is Wildfly or Tomcat or something else that listens on port 8080 installed as a service?  Before killing it, make sure it is Wildfly.

Comment: No. but seems that Netbeans is staartin wildfly twice, but at serves (inside netbeans) it shows that wildfly is not started, but keep saying that the port 8080 is running. Wildfly just strat when a run the project the first time, nothing outside netbean is calling it, i think

Comment: Then it's something in Netbeans. Wildfly isn't starting on it's own.  I might try a fresh project and see if it's still happening.

Comment: same thing with new project =/

Comment: NetBeans WildFly plugin will look to connect to the management port you have configured to check what is the status of the server and not restart it. So if you have a service running then it shouldn't start another server except if you have not properly configured it.